# Run Shell/Linux Commands on Remote after SSH in Windows PowerShell 7 .ps1 Script

Tags: windows, ssh, powershell

I'm running in to noise trying to find the simplest, most straightforward way to run commands on Linux server after SSH in a `.ps1` PowerShell script, running PowerShell 7 on Windows 10.

I have a process that uploads a zip file via SCP/PuTTY, and when completed, my script SSHs in to the server, and from there I need to run a couple Linux commands to unzip the file and run a Docker build/compose.

```
# param1: destination server ip
$ip=$args[0]
# param2: path on the server
$path=$args[1]
# param3: username
$un=$args[2]
# param4: password # TODO: figure out how to hide
$pw=$args[3]
# source path

if (!$pw) { throw "Password can't be null." }

$src = "../"
# construct archival name
$DateTime = (Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddHHmmss")
$zip = "..\deploy_archive\deploy-$DateTime.zip"
# Create archive
mkdir -Force ..\deploy_archive
# exclusion rules. 
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $src -Exclude @("node_modules", "deploy_archive")
# Compress
Compress-Archive -Path $files -DestinationPath $zip -CompressionLevel Fastest
# Report status
Write-Output "`nZipped archive: $($zip)"
# PuTTY SCP file transfer command
$Cmd = ("pscp -l {0} -pw {1} -batch {2} {3}:{4}" -f $un,$pw,$zip,$ip,$path)
Write-Output "cmd: $Cmd"
Invoke-Expression "& $( $Cmd )"
# Report success
Write-Output ("`nUploaded to  {0}:{1}" -f $ip,$path)
# Connect via SSH
ssh ("{0}@{1}" -f $un,$ip)

# ...NOW DO STUFF ON THE REMOTE SERVER
# ...like unzip and run Docker build
```

I am able to add an oldschool ssh command like:

```
ssh username@some.ip.add.ress
```

Then it asks me for my password and connects successfully, but scripts I add after that don't execute until after I exit the SSH session.

If I use:

```
# SSH-Sessions -ComputerName $ip -Username $un -Password $pw
```

I get:

```
> [some.ip.add.ress] The background process reported an error with the
> following message: The SSH client session has ended with error
> message: subsystem request failed on channel 0.
```

`uname -a` on the server gives me:

```
Linux azrahznval0002 3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jan 21 16:15:07 EST 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and part of the answer over on [StackOverflow where a related question was asked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/626574/1253298). I wasn't expecting to find this there... But you can run commands inline with the `ssh` command, which is intuitive, and obvious considering how you'd want to do something like this in most cases.

How am I the first person to post a solution here, lol? Everyone should know this.

Still would like to know why my SSH-Sessions command doesn't work, but that might be something on the server...

Comment: Can you please share your whole solution? I am trying to do the same thing and facing problems. It will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: I don't have that anymore, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply :)

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh myUser@10.0.0.5 @'

    # My Bash commands here.
    # Alternatively, I can invoke PowerShell or Python if installed.

'@
```

Or, for your specific use case:

```
ssh ("{0}@{1}" -f $un, $ip) @'

    # My Bash commands here.
    # Alternatively, I can invoke PowerShell or Python if installed.

'@
```